# How to install ISO file?

Tags: linux, mount, windows, iso, matlab

I've MATLAB R2014a  UNIX ISO file , but i'm using windows 8.1 , how can i install this version  of MATLAB into windows instead of UNIX ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing software under Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if the software is built for Unix then it won't run on Windows.

Second, it sounds like you're trying to mount the ISO in Windows. There are several programs that will do that. Virtual Clone Drive is the first thing that came up when searching.

All of that doesn't count for a hill of beans unless you know what an ISO is. To be basic, an ISO is an image file that contains data generally from a optical medium (CD\DVD\BluRay). You can make ISOs from ripping a CD\DVD\BluRay and making sure you copy all of the sectors. Conversely, you can burn ISOs to a CD\DVD\BluRay as well and have a "perfect" replication.

Comment: is there not anyway to mount this one ? @SailorCire

Comment: @AhmedHaredy Yes, you can mount it using Virtual Clone Drive or as Renan mentioned, daemon tools. However, if the software is built for Unix, as you said in your original question, then it won't install. This is true even if you mount it.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the ISO on Windows (e.g. [DAEMON Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/por/downloads), and [seems that](http://www.wikihow.com/Mount-an-ISO-Image#Mounting_in_Windows_8_sub) Windows 8.1 has a native ISO mounting function), but even then it's useless, as the Linux/UNIX binary will not run on Windows - except, of course, if you install Linux in a virtual machine.